# fold_tree in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, higher-order-functions

As You may know, there are higher order functions in OCaml, such as fold_left, fold_right, filter etc.

On my course in functional programming had been introduced function named fold_tree, which is something like fold_left/right, not on lists, but on (binary) trees. It looks like this:

```
 let rec fold_tree f a t = 
  match t with
    Leaf -> a |
    Node (l, x, r) -> f x (fold_tree f a l) (fold_tree f a r);;
```

Where tree is defined as:

```
type 'a tree = 
  Node of 'a tree * 'a * 'a tree | 
  Leaf;;
```

OK, here's my question: how does the fold_tree function work? Could you give me some examples and explain in human language?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a style suggestion, put the bars on the beginning of the line.  It makes it clearer where a case begins.  For consistency, the first bar is optional but recommended.

```
type 'a tree = 
  | Node of 'a tree * 'a * 'a tree
  | Leaf;;

let rec fold_tree f a t = 
    match t with
      | Leaf -> a
      | Node (l, x, r) -> f x (fold_tree f a l) (fold_tree f a r);;
```

---

As for how it works, consider the following tree:

```
let t = Node(Leaf, 5, Node(Leaf, 2, Leaf));;
```

With the type `int tree`.

Visually, `t` looks like this:

```
   5
  / \
 ()  2
    / \
   () ()
```

And calling fold_tree, we'd need a function to combine the values.  Based on the usage in the `Node` case, `f` takes 3 arguments, all the same type of the tree's and returns the same.  We'll do this:

```
let f x l r = x + l + r;; (* add all together *)
fold_tree f 1 t;;
```

It would help to understand what happens in each case.  For any `Leaf`, a is returned.  For any `Node`, it combines the stored value and the result of folding the left and right subtrees.  In this case, we're just adding the numbers where each leaf counts as one.  The result on the folding of this tree is `10`.

Comment: Thank You for a great example ;). It helped me understand basics, now i need something more difficult.

Comment: **f takes 3 arguments, all the same type of the tree's and returns the same.** One is the type of the tree, the other two are accumulators of any of the same type, being consistent with the default value matched with a leaf.

Comment: @nlucaroni: It was worded for this particular example, but otherwise you're right.

Answer (score 5):

Let's take an example tree.

```
let t = Node (Node (Leaf, 10, Leaf), 1, Node (Node (Leaf, 20, Leaf), 11, Leaf))
```

The general definition of a [fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29) operation is that you replace constructors by functions, everywhere in the tree.

```
general_fold_tree node leaf t =
    node (node leaf 10 leaf) 1 (node (node leaf 20 leaf) 11 leaf)
```

`node` is a function that constructs a *something* from a left *something*, an element and a right *something*, just like `Node` is a constructor that constructs a tree from a left subtree, a node content and a right subtree. `leaf` is a constant, matching the `Leaf` constant constructor.

```
let rec general_fold_tree (node : 'b -> 'a -> 'b -> 'b) (leaf : 'a) (t : 'a tree) : 'b =
  let recurse t = general_fold_tree node leaf t in
  match t with
  | Node (l, x, r) -> node (recurse l) x (recurse r)
  | Leaf -> leaf
```

Notice that the types of the functions match those of the type definition, except that where the type definition describes the building of an `'a tree`, the fold function describes the building of any `'b`.

Operations that look a lot like the general fold are still called fold. For example, on lists, `List.fold_right` is the general fold according to the definition above; `List.fold_left` is a variation that applies the function the other way round (`fold_left` is equivalent to reverse + `fold_right` + reverse, though it's clearer and more efficient).

Your own `fold_tree` is a simple variation of this general fold where the node function takes its arguments in a different order from the constructor:

```
let equrts_fold_tree f a t =
  let node l x r = f x l r in
  general_fold_tree node a t
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to think about `fold_right` on lists: a list is for instance

```
(1 :: (2 :: (3 :: [])))
```

and you re-interpret the list with a new binary operation in place of :: (and a new constant instead of []).

```
fold_right (+) l 0 = (1 + (2 + (3 + 0)))
```

If you wanted to do absolutely nothing to your list, you could pass the function `cons` as the function and the empty list as the neutral element. So in a sense, `fold_right` is very general: it even allows you not to lose any information at all.

The `fold_tree` in your question is the same idea for the datatype of trees. If you want to re-interpret your tree, you pass it a new function for nodes that will be applied instead of the constructor `Node`. If you wanted to get an identical tree, you could apply it with `Leaf` as neutral and `(fun x l r -> Node (l, x, r))` as function.
Similarly to `fold_left` for lists, this example application is not very interesting, but it means that `fold_left` is a very general transformation (the technical term is [morphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphism)).

You can also sum the elements of the tree with the function `(fun x l r -> x + l + r)`, for instance.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `f` is a three parameter reduction function, `a` is the neutral element of our reduction, and `t` is the root, so:

given a binary like (I don't remember very well the syntax of variant types, so please be condescendent here)

```
let r = Node(Node(Node(Leaf,3,Leaf),2,Node(Leaf,4,Leaf)),1,Node(Node(Leaf,6,Leaf),5,Node(Leaf,7,Leaf)))
```

if you want to sum all the nodes, the function will be called like:

```
let add x y z = x + y + z
fold_tree add 0 r
```

and we'll get `t` matched as a node, so we have:

```
(add 1 (fold_tree add 0 Node(Node(Leaf,3,Leaf),2,Node(Leaf,4,Leaf))) (fold_tree add 0 Node(Node(Leaf,6,Leaf),5,Node(Leaf,7,Leaf))))
```

if we expand it a little bit more, we get:

```
(add 1 (add 2 (fold_tree add 0 Node(Leaf,3,Leaf)) (fold_tree add 0 Node(Leaf,4,Leaf))) (add 5 (fold_tree add 0 Node(Leaf,6,Leaf)) (fold_tree add 0 Node(Leaf,7,Leaf))))
```

and once more, we are matching the leaves:

```
(add 1 (add 2 (add 3 0 0) (add 4 0 0)) (add 5 (add 6 0 0) (add 7 0 0))
(add 1 (add 2 3 4) (add 5 6 7))
(add 1 9 18)
```

to finally get:

```
28
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The OP's `fold_tree` function takes a ternary function as argument, so `(+)` is not going to cut it.

Comment: yeah, I was thinking about Lisp when I wrote the first function, but I had alread fixed it :-p

Comment: There is also no data attached to the leaves of the tree in the OPs data type. And the arguments for the Node constructor are in the wrong order.

Comment: Ouch, and I've seen now that the order of the Node structure is wrong, but I'm NOT fixing that!XDDDD

Answer (score 3):

You might enjoy reading

http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/04/06/catamorphisms-part-two/

http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/04/09/catamorphisms-part-three/

which are in F#, but F# is very similar to OCaml.