# Tree Fold in Rust

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement [tree fold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189514/fold-tree-in-ocaml) in rust. My [first attempt](http://is.gd/gpoRU0) compiles and runs as expected.

```
pub enum Tree<T> {
    Leaf,
    Node(Box<Tree<T>>, T, Box<Tree<T>>)
}

impl<T, U: Copy> Tree<T> {
    fn fold(self, f: |l: U, x: T, r: U| -> U, acc: U) -> U {
        match self {
            Leaf => acc,
            Node(box l, x, box r) => {
                let l = l.fold(|l,x,r| {f(l,x,r)}, acc);
                let r = r.fold(|l,x,r| {f(l,x,r)}, acc);
                f(l, x, r)
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let tl = Node(box Leaf, 1i, box Leaf);
    let tr = Node(box Leaf, 2i, box Leaf);
    let t  = Node(box tl, 3i, box tr);

    println!("size(t) == {}", t.fold(|l,_,r|{l + 1i + r}, 0))
}
```

However, when I try to move the [implementation](http://is.gd/veWxoD) of `size` into the `impl` block to make it a method:

```
pub enum Tree<T> {
    Leaf,
    Node(Box<Tree<T>>, T, Box<Tree<T>>)
}

impl<T, U: Copy> Tree<T> {
    fn fold(self, f: |l: U, x: T, r: U| -> U, acc: U) -> U {
        match self {
            Leaf => acc,
            Node(box l, x, box r) => {
                let l = l.fold(|l,x,r| {f(l,x,r)}, acc);
                let r = r.fold(|l,x,r| {f(l,x,r)}, acc);
                f(l, x, r)
            }
        }
    }

    fn size(self) -> uint {
        self.fold(|l, _, r| {l + 1u + r}, 0u)
    } 
}

fn main() {
    let tl = Node(box Leaf, 1i, box Leaf);
    let tr = Node(box Leaf, 2i, box Leaf);
    let t  = Node(box tl, 3i, box tr);

    println!("size(t) == {}", t.size())
}
```

I get the following error in the rust playpen.

```
<anon>:28:31: 28:39 error: cannot determine a type for this expression: unconstrained type
<anon>:28     println!("size(t) == {}", t.size())
                                    ^~~~~~~~
note: in expansion of format_args!
<std macros>:2:23: 2:77 note: expansion site
<std macros>:1:1: 3:2 note: in expansion of println!
<anon>:28:5: 29:2 note: expansion site
error: aborting due to previous error
playpen: application terminated with error code 101
Program ended.
```

I was hoping someone could shed some light on what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a crucial difference between your two things.

In the first, you had this:

```
t.fold(|l,x,r|{l + x + r}, 0)
```

In the second, you have this (shown with `self` changed to `t`):

```
t.fold(|l, x, r| {l + 1 + r}, 0)
```

See the difference? `l + 1 + r` is not `l + x + r`.

*(Since then, all cases have become `l + 1 + r`, for size, rather than `l + x + r`, for sum.)*

After you’ve done that, you’ll run into issues because `uint` is not `int`. You’ll need to sort out your `T`s and `U`s. Basically, you want `l`, `x`, `r` and `0` all to be of the same type, the `T` of earlier. This requires further constraints on `T`:

- It must be `Copy`, to satisfy `U`.
- You must be able to add a `T` to a `T` and get a `T`. This is `std::num::Add<T, T>`.
- You must be able to get a zero of type `T`. That is the `std::num::Zero` trait and the `Zero::zero()` method.
- You must be able to get a one of type `T`. That is the `std::num::One` trait and the `One::one()` method.

While we’re at it, `U` should probably be a generic on the `fold` function specifically rather than the `impl` block, though either will do.

In the end, we end up with this [functioning code](http://is.gd/bJX6B9):

```
use std::num::Zero;

pub enum Tree<T> {
    Leaf,
    Node(Box<Tree<T>>, T, Box<Tree<T>>)
}

impl<T> Tree<T> {
    fn fold<U: Copy>(self, f: |l: U, x: T, r: U| -> U, acc: U) -> U {
        match self {
            Leaf => acc,
            Node(box l, x, box r) => {
                let l = l.fold(|l, x, r| f(l, x, r), acc);
                let r = r.fold(|l, x, r| f(l, x, r), acc);
                f(l, x, r)
            }
        }
    }
}

impl<T: Copy + Add<T, T> + Zero + One> Tree<T> {
    fn size(self) -> T {
        self.fold(|l: T, _: T, r: T| l + One::one() + r, Zero::zero())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let tl = Node(box Leaf, 1i, box Leaf);
    let tr = Node(box Leaf, 2i, box Leaf);
    let t = Node(box tl, 3i, box tr);

    println!("size(t) == {}", t.size())
}
```

(Note how the curly braces around the contents of a closure aren’t necessary, too.)

Comment: Good catch; I do see the difference! Though, implementing size as a method, rather than in main, still produces errors. I'll edit my question to make this clearer. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @mwhittaker: I’ve finished off the answer (I had to go for a bit).

Comment: Wow! Quite an impressive and instructive answer. You implemented a function which sums every element in the tree. Could you also help implement a function that computes the number of nodes in the tree? That is what I intended with the `{l + 1 + r}` logic.

Comment: @mwhittaker: duly updated; `1` is replaced with `One::one()`. Once you have zero and one, you can do anything in a generic numeric fashion!